# how to tell if iptables are now blocking a url

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, firewall, iptables

I am using ubuntu and have blocked outgoing connections to a few ips with iptables. How can I tell if an attempt to violate this rule is made (e.g. some process is trying to access this ip).  Is there some kind of event/callback mechanism (preffered)? Is there a log I can track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iptables -L -v
```

will display your current iptables configuration, along with packet and bytes counters that matched each rule.

Alternatively, you can insert a new rule to iptables, that will log all packets matching some rule:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/iptables-log-packets/